# How to set CRUD in a subpackage with Play

Tags: module, playframework, crud

I am trying to use the CRUD module in subpackages instead of the default one.

```
package controllers.admin;

import models.Branch;
import controllers.CRUD;

    @CRUD.For(Branch.class)
    public class Branches extends CRUD {

        public static void index() {
            render();
        }

    }
```

My routes file is:

```
# Import CRUD routes
*       /admin                                       module:crud
```

However when I use the default url: http://localhost:9000/admin/
I get the template not found error:

```
Template not found
The template admin/Branches/index.html does not exist.
```

How can I specify to CRUD module to look for views in the subpackages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. controller was generated with eclipse plugin and included the index() method.
Removing it solved the problem and the module is now working correctly.

Comment: Note: to get the play crud:override to work I had to amend the python script crud\commands.py to place the views in the admin folder: 'app/views/%s/%s.html' --> 'app/views/admin/%s/%s.html'